# NSFileManager, file extension

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsfilemanager

I am creating an iPhone application which makes a iphone act as a pendrive for easy file sharing.

In the first stage, i have some files(png, pdf, jpg, zip) in a directory and i made them display in the tableview in the form of mutable array. It displays in the tableView as shown below,

```
.DS_Store
.localized
gazelle.pdf
Hamburger_sandwich.jpg
IITD TAJ Picture 028_jpg.jpg
iya_logo_final_b&w.jpg
manifesto09-eng.pdf
RSSReader.sql
SimpleURLConnections.zip
SQLTutorial
```

I just want to display the name of the files and i do not want to display the extensions. I know that it is possible to extract the extensions of a file in NSFileManager. But i do not know how. Please help me to make my table view look like this

```
.DS_Store
.localized
gazelle
Hamburger_sandwich
IITD TAJ Picture 028_jpg
iya_logo_final_b&w
manifesto09-eng
RSSReader
SimpleURLConnections
SQLTutorial
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into NSString's documentation, there you'll find `stringByDeletingPathExtension`.

The basic idea is that you do not want to update objects in existing array, but create a new array with filenames without extension, and throw the original array away.

This is how it can be done:

```
NSArray *stuff = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.jpg", @"image2.png", @"image3.tiff", nil];
NSLog(@"input %@", stuff);

stuff = [stuff valueForKey:@"stringByDeletingPathExtension"];
NSLog(@"output %@", stuff);
```

I do not expect you to understand that code, therefore here's a more straightforward version:

```
NSArray *stuff = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.jpg", @"image2.png", @"image3.tiff", nil];
NSLog(@"input %@", stuff);

NSMutableArray *output = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *filename in stuff) {
    NSString *filenameWithoutExtension = [filename stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    [output addObject:filenameWithoutExtension];
}
NSLog(@"output %@", output);
```

Comment: How can i use stringByDeletingPathExtension for a mutable array? any idea?

Comment: You should consider investing some time to learn the very basics of programming, only then come to stackoverflow - site for programmers.